# Fixing warnings from Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, warnings

I am currently working on a Hibernate project. My current development setup has a rather long debug printout on startup, from alot of hibernate warnings.
I would like to clean this up.

> 2009-02-18 09:14:19
>   org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter
>   logWarnings WARNING:
>   [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for
>   JDBC][SQLServer]Changed language
>   setting to us_english.

How do i fix this one? Google was unable to give me the answer

> 2009-02-18 09:14:19 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
>   WARNING: SQL Warning: 0, SQLState:

This i dont understand. Can anyone explain?

> 2009-02-18 09:48:36 org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logWarnings
>   WARNING: [Microsoft][SQLServer 2000 Driver for JDBC][SQLServer]Changed database context to 'bess_test'.

How do i specify the Database, to avoid this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa197373(SQL.80).aspx

According to this, the Changed language setting and the Changed Database context, are supposed to be reported as warnings and are supposed to be ignored.

Can this really be true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find this helpful in the future when you want to turn on logging for a specific part of Hibernate.  This configuration should also hide the warnings that you are seeing.

```
# Hibernate logging
# Log everything (a lot of information, but very useful for troubleshooting)
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=FATAL
# Log all SQL DML statements as they are executed
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=INHERITED
# Log all JDBC parameters
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=INHERITED
# Log all SQL DDL statements as they are executed
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=INHERITED
# Log the state of all entities (max 20 entities) associated with the session at flush time
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.pretty=INHERITED
# Log all second-level cache activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=INHERITED
# Log all OSCache activity - used by Hibernate
log4j.logger.com.opensymphony.oscache=INHERITED
# Log transaction related activity
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.transaction=INHERITED
# Log all JDBC resource acquisition
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=INHERITED
# Log all JAAS authorization requests
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.secure=INHERITED
```